# Javascript random number generator in range, going below and above the given range

Tags: javascript, html, random, numbers

I have been trying to make a random number generator, with a given range, thought it would be easy and then without any logical reason the random number isnt in any way affected by the given maximum and minimum range. Please help. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
           <head>
             <style>
                .elements {
                text-align: center;
                 }

           .random {
                margin-top: 100px;
                width: 275px;
                height: 200px;
                font-size: 50px;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .range {
                margin: 35px 25px;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 30px;
            }

            .generate {
                margin-top: 50px;
                width: 250px;
                height: 35px;
                font-size: 20px;
            }
        </style>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function rand()
            {
                var max = document.getElementById("max").value;
                var min = document.getElementById("min").value;

                var output = document.getElementById("output");

                var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * max + min);

                output.value = random;
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="elements">

        <input type="text" class="random" id="output">
        <br>
        <input type="button" class="generate" value="Generate random number" onclick="rand();">
        <br>
        <h1>Maximum Number</h1>
        <input type="text" class="range" id="max">
        <h1>Minimal Number</h1>
        <input type="text" class="range" id="min">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random() * max + min);` This causes that `Math.random()` is multiplicated with `max` and after that, `min` is added via the plus.

Answer (score 3):

You need to multiply `Math.random()` by the *length of your range*, not by the maximum value in the range.

```js
const getRandom = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
Array.from({ length: 20 }, () => console.log(getRandom(0, 2)));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `document.getElementById("max").value` is string, so now `Math.random() * max + min` is `float * string + string`, which append min value as string. `parseInt` will resolve this issue.
2. `Math.random() * max + min` is incorrect. `Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min` is right.

Comment: But in my browser, `0.01 * "10" + "999"` is 0.1999.

Comment: Yes, multiplication coerces the string to a number, but addition does not.

Answer (score 0):

Add a code block that checks if the random number generated falls in the range specified. If it doesn't loop through random number generation until the condition test fails;

```js
function rand() {
  var max = document.getElementById("max").value;
  var min = document.getElementById("min").value;

  var output = document.getElementById("output");


  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * max + min);

  while (random > max || random < min) {
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * max + min);
  }

  output.value = random;

}
```

```css
.elements {
  text-align: center;
}

.random {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 275px;
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.range {
  margin: 35px 25px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.generate {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elements">
  <input type="text" class="random" id="output">
  <br>
  <input type="button" class="generate" value="Generate random number" onclick="rand();">
  <br>
  <h1>Maximum Number</h1>
  <input type="text" class="range" id="max">
  <h1>Minimal Number</h1>
  <input type="text" class="range" id="min">
```

after that, you can then assign the its value to output.

Answer (score 0):

using this code:

```
// the initial seed
Math.seed = 6;

// in order to work 'Math.seed' must NOT be undefined,
// so in any case, you HAVE to provide a Math.seed
Math.seededRandom = function(max, min) {
    max = max || 1;
    min = min || 0;

    Math.seed = (Math.seed * 9301 + 49297) % 233280;
    return Math.floor(min + (Math.seed / 233280) * (max - min));
}
var res = Math.seededRandom(100,-100)
console.log(res)
```

or try it yourself

http://indiegamr.com/generate-repeatable-random-numbers-in-js/